# Sitecore Commerce 9 Update 1 installation problem

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I was trying to install sitecore commerce 9 update 1 through **"Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1"** But unfortunately i am ended up with the below error:

```
[-------------------------------- DeployCommerceContentOps : DeployCommerceContent -----------------------------------
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CommerceServicesDbServer'.
This error might have been caused by applying the default parameter binding. You can disable the default parameter
binding in $PSDefaultParameterValues by setting $PSDefaultParameterValues["Disabled"] to be $true, and then trying
again. The following default parameters were successfully bound for this cmdlet when the error occurred: -Verbose
-WarningAction -InformationAction -ErrorAction -Debug
At C:\program
files\windowspowershell\modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.2\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:254 char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
```

Any idea would be highly appreciate. My ps1 file is as follows:

```
<pre>
  #Requires -Version 3

param(
    [string]$SiteName = "sxafront", 
    [string]$SiteHostHeaderName = "sxafront.storefront.com",    
    [string]$SqlDbPrefix = "sxafront",
    [string]$CommerceSearchProvider = "SOLR"
)

$global:DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY=Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$modulesPath=( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "Modules" )
if ($env:PSModulePath -notlike "*$modulesPath*")
{
    $p = $env:PSModulePath + ";" + $modulesPath
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath",$p)
}


$params = @{
        Path = Resolve-Path '.\Configuration\Commerce\Master_SingleServer.json' 
        SiteName = "$($SiteName).sc"
        SiteHostHeaderName = $SiteHostHeaderName 
        InstallDir = "$($Env:SYSTEMDRIVE)\inetpub\wwwroot\$($SiteName).sc"
        XConnectInstallDir = "$($Env:SYSTEMDRIVE)\inetpub\wwwroot\$($SiteName).xconnect"
        CertificateName = "$($SiteName).sc"
        CommerceServicesDbServer = "LT-MDA2-T-MY\MSSQLSERVER2"
        CommerceServicesDbName = "SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments"
        CommerceServicesGlobalDbName = "SitecoreCommerce9_Global"       
        SitecoreDbServer ="LT-MDA2-T-MY\MSSQLSERVER2"
        SitecoreCoreDbName = "$($SqlDbPrefix)_Core"
        SitecoreUsername = "sitecore\admin"
        SitecoreUserPassword = "b"
        CommerceSearchProvider = $CommerceSearchProvider
        SolrUrl = "https://lt-mda2-t-my.dk.sitecore.net:8991/solr"
        SolrRoot = "c:\\solr-6.6.2"
        SolrService = "Solr-6.6.2"
        SolrSchemas = ( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "SolrSchemas" )
        SearchIndexPrefix = "commercedemo"
        AzureSearchServiceName = ""
        AzureSearchAdminKey = ""
        AzureSearchQueryKey = ""
        CommerceEngineDacPac = Resolve-Path -Path "..\assets\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.DB.dacpac"       
        CommerceOpsServicesPort = "5015"
        CommerceShopsServicesPort = "5005"
        CommerceAuthoringServicesPort = "5000"
        CommerceMinionsServicesPort = "5010"        
        SitecoreCommerceEngineZipPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.2.1.55.zip"     
        SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.BizFX.1.1.9"     
        SitecoreIdentityServerZipPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.IdentityServer.1.1.3.zip"
        CommerceEngineCertificatePath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\assets\EngineConnect.crt"        
        SiteUtilitiesSrc = Resolve-Path -Path "..\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.0.1748\SiteUtilityPages"  
        HabitatImagesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Habitat.Images-1.0.0.zip"    
        AdvImagesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Adventure Works Images.zip"    
        CommerceConnectModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Connect Core 11.1.78.zip"  
        CEConnectPackageFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.2.1.54.update"
        PowerShellExtensionsModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\assets\Sitecore PowerShell Extensions-4.7.2 for Sitecore 8.zip"
        SXAModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\assets\Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.6 rev. 180103 for 9.0.zip"
        SXACommerceModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator 1.1.47.zip"
        SXAStorefrontModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront 1.1.47.zip"
        SXAStorefrontThemeModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront Themes 1.1.47.zip"
        SXAStorefrontCatalogModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Habitat Catalog 1.1.47.zip"
        MergeToolFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\assets\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"
        UserAccount = @{
            Domain = $Env:COMPUTERNAME
            UserName = 'CSFndRuntimeUser'
            Password = 'Tbinfo28121981'
        }
        BraintreeAccount = @{
            MerchantId = 'ps4jmc83q4j5fzcp'
            PublicKey = 'xf5nx6yswqk2jyvk'
            PrivateKey = '5603f9ebe5fbad9be7f0d1ff6a650884'
        }
        SitecoreIdentityServerName = "SitecoreIdentityServer"       
    }

if ($CommerceSearchProvider -eq "SOLR") {
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params
}
elseif ($CommerceSearchProvider -eq "AZURE"){
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -Skip InstallSolrCores
}

</pre>
```

Comment: In particular, make sure that the path values correspond to the locations 
 where you unzipped or copied files needed for the installation.

Comment: Make sure you can access your SQL server 'LT-MDA2-T-MY\MSSQLSERVER2' like this, that what is the error saying. The script is failing as it cannot find this sql server or it is not reachable. You may have to configure it properly if it is a new installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing both installations: initial XC9 and XC9 Update 1.

According to your logs, it fails when calling `DeployCommerceContent` task.

This is how this task looks in initial XC9:

```
Function Invoke-DeployCommerceContentTask {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$ServicesContentPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$PhysicalPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [psobject[]]$UserAccount = @(),
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [psobject[]]$BraintreeAccount = @(),
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$CommerceSearchProvider,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SitecoreDbServer,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SitecoreCoreDbName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$CommerceServicesDbName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$CommerceServicesGlobalDbName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SiteHostHeaderName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$CommerceAuthoringServicesPort,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SolrUrl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SearchIndexPrefix,     
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$AzureSearchServiceName,        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$AzureSearchAdminKey,       
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$AzureSearchQueryKey        
    )
```

This is XC9 Update 1:

```
Function Invoke-DeployCommerceContentTask {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$ServicesContentPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$PhysicalPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [psobject[]]$UserAccount = @(),
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [psobject[]]$BraintreeAccount = @(),
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$CommerceSearchProvider,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SitecoreDbServer,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SitecoreCoreDbName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$CommerceServicesDbServer, // this is new param introduced in XC 9 Update 1
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$CommerceServicesDbName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$CommerceServicesGlobalDbName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SiteHostHeaderName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$CommerceAuthoringServicesPort,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SolrUrl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SearchIndexPrefix,     
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$AzureSearchServiceName,        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$AzureSearchAdminKey,       
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$AzureSearchQueryKey        
    )
```

So your parent task passes an object that is not expected by the task declaration.

Try downloading latest XC9 Update 1 package from [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Commerce/90/Sitecore_Experience_Commerce_90_Update1.aspx) and install again.